# How to trim a field by index from the right of a string in Bash?

Tags: string, bash, shell, field, cut

I would like to remove "(field 5)" from the following string:

```
test_string="[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 4) (field 5) (field 6)"
```

Problems:

- Sometimes `(field 4)` doesn't even exist.
- I just want to keep `(field 6)` at the end of the string no matter what.
- Sometimes I don't have any field after at all "field 3", in which case I just keep the string as is, ie. `[field 1 (field 2)] field 3`

So far the only way to do it way very dirty:

```
$ first_fields="$(printf "${test_string[@]}" | cut -d'(' -f -2)"

$ echo $first_field
> [field 1 (field 2)] field 3

$ last_field="$(printf "(${test_string##*\(}")"

$ echo "$last_field"
> (field 6)
```

Problem here:

- if I have a variable number of fields, I can't `cut -f` a hard coded field number value otherwise I'll lose `(field 4)`
- All I need is to keep the very last `(field)` at the right end of the string, no matter what it is.

**Question: how to count fields from the right end of the string?** Or am I pushing over the limit of Unix shells' capabilities?

I have tried the following but I always get one field only which is the entire string itself:

```
IFS="("
for i in "${test_string[@]}";
do
    echo "field is: $i"
done
> [field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 4) (field 5) (field 6)
```

Note:  the fields are always between parentheses and contain totally random characters every time (worse, they are foreign languages encoded in unicode).

Comment: I have also tried with `mapfile -t mapped_string <<<(printf "$test_string")` but it's the same number of fields, ie. 1.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You've obviously done a good job trying to work it out. What is the structure of each field? Presumably it's some string with some defined rules (for example no spaces, N characters, does not contain any brackets, etc.) - the rules may make it very difficult or very hard to parse any such line accurately.

Comment: The fields contains random characters, sometimes they have spaces, sometimes not.

Comment: What is definition of a field? What makes `(field 5)` a single field instead of 2 separate fields since there is a whitespace.

Comment: A field is always delimited by the two parentheses, except the field 1 and field 3, which are always between their opening/closing brackets. There can be spaces in fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression anchored to the end.

```
#!/bin/bash
test_string="[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 4) (field 5) (field 6)"
rgx_field="[(].*[)]"
rgx_space="[[:space:]]*"
if
  [[ $test_string =~ (.*)$rgx_field$rgx_space($rgx_field)$rgx_space$ ]]
then
  result="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" # Removed
else
  result=$test_string # No match... Buggy data?
fi
echo "$result"
```

This assumes fields are enclosed in parentheses, just like your sample code.

The key line is this :

```
[[ $test_string =~ (.*)$rgx_field$rgx_space($rgx_field)$rgx_space$ ]]
```

The `=~` operator tries to match the string on the left with the extended regular expression on the right.  The parts of the line that are inside parentheses are instructions to the regex matching engine to "remember" those parts (which are then available in the `BASH_REMATCH` array).  The trailing `$` indicates that this regular expression has to match the end of the string, so that it works "backwards" from the last field.  The leading fields are all matched by the initial `(.*)`.

Comment: Wow thank you, this seems to be just what I was looking for. I'll go read more about regex processing in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `sed`:

```
$> test_string="[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 4) (field 5) (field 6)"
$> sed -E 's/^(.*)\([^)]*\) (\([^)]*\))$/\1\2/' <<< "$test_string"
[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 4) (field 6)

$> test_string="[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 5) (field 6)"
$> sed -E 's/^(.*)\([^)]*\) (\([^)]*\))$/\1\2/' <<< "$test_string"
[field 1 (field 2)] field 3 (field 6)
```

This `sed` command uses a regex to remove (last -1)th `(...)` value from input.